# Android native library linking against another native library from aar

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, multiplatform

I have a curious question. I have an aar library, which contains and uses native .so library. Now, I want to write another lib, which depends on that library and also has native part depending on native lib from the first lib. The dependent library uses both the native code and java wrappers from the first lib.

I wonder, is there any way, how to do this by standard gradle dependency(with copied headers files from the first lib)? Or have I to build the second lib directly from the sources?

Why I need this:
We have a multiplatform lib with basic functionality, for android as aar. This lib can be used in standard android app and we use it in multiple projects, which have no another native code.

But in one app we want to write multiplatform shared app code, depending on that lib and I want to have these libs separated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE**: This answer is deprecated, since Android Studio on longer provide `explored-aar` directory.

For a better solution to use headers from `aar`, check the library [androidNativeBundle](https://github.com/howardpang/androidNativeBundle)

[Here](https://github.com/WanghongLin/OpenCV4Android) is a workable example basic on `OpenCV`, you can do the same for your `first lib`.

#### Prepare first lib as following

Package the `jar`, `*.so`, and exported `headers` (see the file `OpenCV4Android/opencv/build.gradle` in the linked project how to append the headers to aar).

You get `first.aar` for example from the building of `first lib`.

#### Using first lib in your other projects

Add the `first.aar` in your other projects when you needed.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        flatDir {
            dirs '/path/to/aar'
        }
    }
}

// in your app's build.gradle
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.example:example-with-header@aar'
    // ...
}
```

Link against your native library to the `first.aar` from your native build system.

If you use `CMake`, it should look like this

```
add_library(first
SHARED
IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(
first
PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
../../../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.example/example-debug/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/libfirst.so
# use find command to figure out the location of the first lib before use it, not sure if it's different in different build environment
# for android studio gradle plugin latest version use
# ../../../../build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/folders/2000/1f/main/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libfirst.so
)

# also use find command to figure the actual location of the exported header from aar
# this might be different in your environment for different version of gradle plugin
include_directories(build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.example/example-debug/cpp/include)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       first
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since the android studio doesn't create the exploded-aar directory.

Comment: Yes, the new Android studio has removed `exploded-aar` directory, i have recommended a new approach in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From Android Studio 4.0, a new mechanism called [Prefab](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/native-dependencies-in-android-studio-40.html) is supported by AGP (Android Gradle Plugin). This uses a specially prepared AAR that can be listed in your project dependencies just like you have other external libraries, and you get the headers and build flags necessary to link to the library from CMake or ndk-build.

This resembles the [exploded-aar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713565/192373) by @alijandro, but it's officially supported, and requires much less boilerplate. E.g. you will only need

```
find_package(first REQUIRED CONFIG)
target_link_libraries(app first::libfirst)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned Gradle, I am assuming you are using the
latest Android Studio. I am using 1.2.2 and found it easy to
build the simple NDK projects from the many tutorials floating
around, but frustratingly difficult to build an NDK project of
any complexity. I will summarize what I found, but I highly
suggest reading 
[this blog](https://www.crystax.net/en/blog/3#)
and [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765465/android-ndk-two-static-libraries-and-linking).

My project is similar to yours but not exactly. The trick for me
was figuring out how to make Android Studio use my Android.mk, then
finding the right makefile variables. Hopefully this will help.

The stock Android Studio will completely ignore any custom
Android.mk file you create, and instead auto-generate its own.
To correct this, you must first hack the *build.gradle*
script for your project, located at `project/app/build.gradle`.
You could probably hack the top-level build.gradle, if desired.

This is my hacked build.gradle. I build on a Windows box, so I
hacked it for Windows only. Uncomment the lines if you are using OSX
or Linux.

**project/app/build.gradle:**

```
//import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  //ENABLE CUSTOM ANDROID.MK >>
  sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs= [] //Disable automatic ndk-build.
  sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'

  //Call regular ndk-build script from app directory
  task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    workingDir file('src/main')
    commandLine getNdkBuildCmd()
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -&gt; compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
  }

  task cleanNative(type: Exec) {
    workingDir file('src/main')
    commandLine getNdkBuildCmd(), 'clean'
  }

  clean.dependsOn cleanNative
}
//ENABLE CUSTOM ANDROID.MK <<

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}

//ENABLE CUSTOM ANDROID.MK >>
def getNdkDir() {
  if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT != null)
    return System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT

  Properties properties = new Properties()
  properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
  def ndkdir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)
  if (ndkdir == null)
    throw new GradleException("NDK location not found. Define location with ndk.dir in the local.properties file")

  return (ndkdir)
}

def getNdkBuildCmd() {
  def ndkbuild = getNdkDir() + "/ndk-build.cmd"
//  def ndkbuild = getNdkDir() + "/ndk-build"
//  if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))
//    ndkbuild += ".cmd"
  return ndkbuild
}
//ENABLE CUSTOM ANDROID.MK <<
```

Now I can create my multi-library Android.mk. This builds
two static-link libraries, then builds the final dynamic-link
libraries and links in the first two. The directories involved
are:

**Directories:**

```
project/
  app/
    build.gradle
    src/
      main/
        java/
        jni/
          Android.mk
          include/
          libmp3lame/
          MiniMp3/
          mp3_jni.c
          mpglib/
```

**Android.mk:**

```
TOP_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)/libmp3lame
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(TOP_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DSTDC_HEADERS

LOCAL_MODULE                := libmp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := \
bitstream.c \
...
version.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
MY_LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libmp3lame

LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)/mpglib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(TOP_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(TOP_PATH)/libmp3lame
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DSTDC_HEADERS
LOCAL_MODULE := mpglib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
common.c \
...
tabinit.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
MY_LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += mpglib

LOCAL_PATH := $(TOP_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(TOP_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DSTDC_HEADERS
LOCAL_MODULE := Mp3
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := $(MY_LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./mp3_jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You will need to tweak the Android.mk.

Comment: This isn't what I mean. I already have working gradle with custom makefiles and some other tweaks for building neon and no-neon variants, similar to your solution. My question is if it is possible link one native project against so lib packed in another aar library. But as I think about it, it is not possible...